# troubleshoot percent function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

https://jsfiddle.net/kelliwilli/6bgrt7bL/128/

```
var percent = function() {
  var totalGames = (scores.draw + scores.p1 + scores.Ali);
  var drawPercent = ((scores.draw / totalGames) * 100);
  var AliPercent = ((scores.Ali / totalGames) * 100);
  var p1Percent = ((scores.p1 / totalGames) * 100;

  alert ("There has been " + drawPercent + "% of draws. I won " +     AliPercent + "%, and" +p1 +" won" + p1Percent "%!");
}
```

Comment: You'll get better help if you mention what the expected versus actual behavior is. Also if you show us what `scores` contains.

Comment: var scores = {
    draw: 0,
    p1: 0, 
    Ali: 0,
 };

Comment: I want to show percentages of wins, but when I add this function the program won't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/kelliwilli/6bgrt7bL/224/

```
//percent funtion
  var percent = function() {
    var totalGames = (scores.draw + scores.p1 + scores.Ali);
    var drawPercent = ((scores.draw / totalGames) * 100);
    var AliPercent = ((scores.Ali / totalGames) * 100);
    var p1Percent = ((scores.p1 / totalGames) * 100);
    alert("There has been " + drawPercent + "% of draws. Ali won " + AliPercent + "%, and " + p1 + " won " + p1Percent + "% of the games! Thanks for playing!!!");
  }
```

There was some code out of sequence, calling a function before it was defined, and an "if" loop that should have been a "while".
Simple fixes. :)

This fiddle link works!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to just be a simple syntax error, which is not what I thought you were getting at with the question or lack of...

Anyways `alert ("There has been " + drawPercent + "% of draws. I won " +     AliPercent + "%, and" +p1 +" won" + p1Percent + "%!");` should fix it. You simply forgot to concat the last variable.

Look into template literals, they're super handy for throwing together strings with many variables, along with the fact I find them to be awesome syntax wise.

Template literal form:

```
alert(`There has been ${drawPercent}% of draws. I won ${AliPercent}%, and ${p1} won ${p1Percent}%!});
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I read that so many times and missed it.